# read namespace variables and inline static variables

Tags: c++

I'm using Qt creator with GDB on linux

When I debug my program the local tab shows my

```
inline static int i = 12;
```

as 'optimized out' and there is no value for the i variable

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: whats the question? You want to use the debugger in a release build ?

Comment: @Raildex ? what makes you believe the word "local" is the issue here?

Comment: First question was solved by expressions tab thank you but how about seconds one why I cannot read inline static int i value

Comment: do you know what "inline" does?